# Entity Framework C# - DbGeometry POLYGON doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-4.5, sql-server-2016-localdb

i have a problem with WKT and DbGeometry working together.
When i use POINT as geometry like this example it works good.

```
DbGeometry myGeometry1 = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT (30 10)");
DbGeometry myGeometry2 = DbGeometry.PointFromText("POINT (30 10)", 0);
```

if i use POLYGON or any other geometry instead, it doesn't work at all.

```
DbGeometry myGeometry3 = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))");
DbGeometry myGeometry4 = DbGeometry.PolygonFromText("POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))", 0);
```

This is the Platform Stack:

Entity Framework 6
ASP.NET 4.5
SQLServer 2016 LocalDB

Comment: I came a year late... it actually does work for me. Which exact error message do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install **SQLSysClrTypes_x86.msi** and **SQLSysClrTypes_x64.msi**

from Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22955563)

Comment: I got your point, it actually happened to me many times.
In that case just google for Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack